# Critical Points and Gradients/Derivatives

Tags: calculus, optimization, proof-writing

Plot the function $f(x)= 3+\cos(3x)-0.5\sin(5x)+0.2\cos\left(10x-\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)\right)$.
Estimate how many critical points are on the interval $[0,2\pi]$.

Consider $\mathbb{R}^{20} \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $g(\mathbf{x})=f(x_1)f(x_2)\cdots f(x_{20})$. Show that $\nabla g(\mathbf{x})=0$ is equivalent to $f'(x_i)=0$ for all $i$.

I used wolfram alpha to graph the function and this is what I got...

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=criticial+points+f%28x%29%3D3%2Bcos%283x%29-0.5sin%285x%29%2B0.2cos%2810x-%28pi%2F4%29%29+from+0+to+2pi

I would say there are approximately $12$ critical points.

I don't know how to show that $\nabla g(\mathbf{x})=0$ is equivalent to $f'(x_i)=0$ however...

Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: It looks like the latter statement is not true in general (use $f(x)=x$ for counterexample).  Can you check the wording of the problem and any assumptions that might be present?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like 12 critical points to me.

$$\nabla g(x)=\left[\begin{array}{c} f'(x_1)f(x_2)f(x_3)\cdots f(x_{20})\\
f(x_1)f'(x_2)f(x_3)\cdots f(x_{20})\\
f(x_1)f(x_2)f'(x_3)\cdots f(x_{20})\\
\vdots \\
f(x_1)f(x_2)f(x_3)\cdots f'(x_{20})\end{array}\right].$$
Note carefully the placement of the $'$ symbols.

What do you need to prove that each of those rows equals zero?

EDIT:

It appears that $f'(x_i)=0$ for all $i$ is only one of the conditions giving $\nabla g(x)=0$.  We could also have $f(x_i)=0$ for all $i$, or $f(x_1)=f'(x_1)=0$ for example.

Consider $f(x)=x$.  Then $g(x)=x^{20}$ and $$\nabla g(x)=\left[\begin{array}{c} 1\cdot x_2\cdot x_3\cdots x_{20}\\
x_1\cdot 1 \cdot x_3\cdots x_{20}\\
x_1\cdot x_2\cdot 1\cdots x_{20}\\
\vdots \\
x_1\cdot x_2\cdot x_3\cdots 1\end{array}\right].$$
This is equal to zero when $x_1=x_2=\cdots x_{20}=0$, but $f'(x_i)=1$ for all $i$.

Comment: Does each derivative need to be 0 so there would be a diagonal of 0's in the matrix? Or is it something to do with the determinant?

Comment: It's a column vector, not a matrix.  Each row is a single value: the product of (for the first row) $f'(x_1)f(x_2)f(x_3)\cdot f(x_{20})$.